# Having trouble returning a 2D array from Google script to use in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to return a 2D array from a google spreadsheet using this:

```
function getData(){
      //this function reads data from the sheet and retuns a 2D array
          var spreadsheetID = //spreadsheet ID;
          var range = 'SchoolData!A2:B';
          var data = 
          SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getRange(range).getValues();
          return data;
     }
```

The returned data should be processed in the `compareID()` function upon submission of my HTML form.

```
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick= "authorise()">


    function authorise(){
        alert("inside authorise");
        google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(errMsg)
        .withSuccessHandler(compareID)
        .getData();

    }

    function compareID(data){
        alert("inside compare");
        //process the data
    }


    function errMsg(){
        alert("no data was returned ");
    }
```

My code seems to always go to `errMsg()` and never enters the `compareID()` function. I even tried to use `JSON.stringify(data)` in the Google script file and return a String then `JSON.parse(data)` in the HTML script but still did not get the required results.

What should i do to get my code to enter the `compareID()` function?

Comment: you are passing the result of `errMsg()` instead of the method. Should be `.withFailureHandler(errMsg)`

Comment: @Slai Thank  you I was not aware of that, I'm still getting used to Javascript. However this still did not solve my problem as my code is always jumping to the errMsg() and not to the compareID() function, I think my issue is with the return type but i can't quite figure out what it is.

Comment: @MarioM make sure your question reflects what is giving you an issue. If you made the fix offered by slai but still have the same problem, update the question with your code.

Comment: You should probably also print the error message you get in your failure handler while debugging, i.e. `function errmsg(e) { console.log(e); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code as shown above i get "inside compare".  And data is correct values.  Is errMsg called anywhere else in your html?

```
function test() {
  try {
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_Test');
    var htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Sample");
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function getData(){
  //this function reads data from the sheet and retuns a 2D array
  var spreadsheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var range = 'Sheet2!A2:B';
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getRange(range).getValues();
  return data;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick= "authorise()">
</div>
<script>
  function authorise(){
    alert("inside authorise");
    google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(errMsg)
    .withSuccessHandler(compareID)
    .getData();
  }

  function compareID(data){
    alert("inside compare");
    //process the data
  }

  function errMsg(){
    alert("no data was returned ");
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the Google Sheets API directly, but when using Apps Script you have access to the much more robust and convenient SpreadsheetApp service.

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID).getRange(range).getValues();
```

see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app

Comment: This adds more convenience but it didn't really help solve my issue. Anything else is should be aware of to get the data through to the script in my HTML?

Comment: I was guessing the usage of the Sheets api was causing an error, seems that isn't the case. Do you get an error if you run 'getData' directly from the script editor?  Your approach for returning the data to onSuccess looks correct

Comment: When i debug the `getData()` function i can see that the data is correctly stored in the `data` variable and no error occurs.

Comment: I copied your example code and tested, it works for me.  Is there any code outside of getData() which may be running and causing an error?  Each time you make a call via google.script.run.. a new instance of your script is started, and any code not encapusulated in a function will execute. If that code generates an exception, then getData() won't run.